# Fixed size left column and fluid right column both with 100% height

Tags: html, css, fluid-layout

I'm looking to construct a two-column layout with a fixed left column and a fluid right, both with 100% height, like this example:

[image]

I've tried so many variations I can't remember what I've tried now, and just can't get it to look right. I've also tried looking at websites such as [LayoutGala](http://blog.html.it/layoutgala/) but they don't have any example with both columns having a 100% height.

I can't remember what I have tried already but this was definitely my last attempt. I know this because this was the last visited web page before I was arrested for throwing a computer monitor from the fourth floor of an apartment block.

```
body { margin:0; padding:0; }
.left-column { position:absolute; top:0; width:235px; height:100%; background:#090909; }
.right-column { margin-left:235px; background:yellow; height:100%; width:100%; }


<div class="page-wrapper">
    <div class="left-column"></div>
    <div class="right-columnr">
        sd
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the result here:

[MyFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G9RuL/)

I'm so used to my 960 wide centered website, that when it came to a full screen fluid layout, it completely threw me. Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, you need to fix `right-columnr` typo, Second: when you set a height of `100%` on a element to take the entire height of screen, its parent should have a height of `100%` too:

**CSS:**

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.page-wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.left-column {
  position:fixed; /* <-- fixes the left panel to prevent from scrolling */
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:235px;
  height:100%;
  background:#090909;
}

.right-column {
  margin-left:235px;
  background:yellow;
  min-height:100%;  /* <-- fixes the background-color issue when content grows */
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="page-wrapper">
  <div class="left-column"></div>
  <div class="right-column">
    This is the content.
  </div>
</div>
```

**[JSBin Demo](http://jsbin.com/eLuC/1/edit)**

Answer (score 3):

IF You really want your columns to have 100% height then You must set 100% height on `body` and `html` elements.

This works:

```
html {height: 100%}
body {height: 100%}
.page-wrapper {height: 100%} /* This element is redundant unless You know You will need it in future for something */
.left-column {float: left; width: 235px; height: 100%}
.right-column {overflow: hidden; height: 100%}
```

**Edit:**

Demo based on Your code: http://jsfiddle.net/YL8Eh/

Comment: that solution doesn't help much because you're setting the overflow to hidden?
http://jsfiddle.net/r61zvuk7/